# integrating vicidial in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api

I have to integrate vicidial to my rails app, I just need to add phone no to the list, I searched for this but did not find any useful doc. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic methods (aside from the web interface) to add leads to the vicidial_list table (which is where the leads reside).

1) As previously mentioned: the API
This can be activated from the command line by invoking wget or curl to simulate a web request and using the instructions in NON-AGENT_API.txt regarding the "add_lead" function. The instruction file is in /usr/src/astguiclient/trunk/docs/NON-AGENT_API.txt by default and the api itself is /srv/www/htdocs/vicidial/non_agent_api.php or "http://example.com/vicidial/non_agent_api.php".

2) Command Line Lead Loader
This can be used to add multiple leads at once (or one at a time). It can also be used to reach out and grab leads from an FTP site, which means you'd be able to "plop" the lead in a location and then send Vicidial to "go get it" by invoking the CLILeadLoader.
This script resides in /usr/share/astguiclient/VICIDIAL_IN_new_leads_file.pl, and there are some other related utilities nearby. Instructions and options are available by executing the script with "--help"

Of course, in both cases you could extract the code (one is PHP and one is PERL) if you want to write your own add to database method without invoking another script.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Vicidial NON-Agent API to add phone to list.

Answer (score 0):

On original vicibox installations you will find most of the answers you need in the

```
/usr/src/astguiclient/trunk/docs
```

folder.

For integration with Rails you will most likely want to use the Web Agent API.
There are multiple options to add leads to the system, for example the "external_add_lead" function which you will find in the AGENT_API.txt file.